# how do get two UITextView's in Interface Builder to align properly when going to landscape orientation?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uitextview

how do get two UITextView's in Interface Builder to align properly when going to landscape orientation?

I have one taking up the upper 1/4 roughly of the screen and the other one below taking up the remaining.  Everything is looking good in Portrait.

In landscape however they overlap/don't align properly.  I've been trying the resizing masks but haven't seemed to come up with the right combination.

How can I get them to keep themselves aligned properly during orientation changes (and use in iPad too would be good)

EDIT 1 - Should clarify that I have in fact on this screen, from top to bottow:

- Menu Bar (at top)
- UITextView with heading (bold text)
- UITextView with details text

So not sure if this makes any different to the answer.  Main point is that even when I play with different settings of auto-sizing I can't seem to get it so that after an orientation change the bottom of the high UITextView is still neatly aligned with the top of the lower one (i.e. rather I seem to get an overlap effect)

EDIT 2 - I put borders around both UITextView and infact they are not overlapping in the Landscape mode, but rather the vertical width of the top UITextView (for the heading) seems to shrink such that it cuts off the 2nd/bottom line of the two line heading.

Comment: What happens if you fill in every arrow in the autoresizing ui for both text views, except the bottom one for the top guy and the top one for the bottom guy?

Comment: @Colin - yep had tried this - what happens here in landscape mode is that the bottom view comes up too high over the lower part of the top view...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set your autoresizing mask properly, ask yourself these six questions:

1. Do I want the **height** of my view to change when the height of its container changes?  If so, **enable** the **vertical spring** with the up/down arrows in IB.  This is equivalent to setting `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.
2. Do I want the **distance** between the **top** of my view and the top of its container to change when the height of the container changes?  If so, **disable** the **top strut** in IB.  This is equivalent to setting `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`.
3. Do I want the **distance** between the **bottom** of my view and the bottom of its container to change when the height of the container changes?  If so, **disable** the **bottom strut** in IB.  This is equivalent to setting `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`.
4. Do I want the **width** of my view to change when the width of its container changes?  If so, **enable** the **horizontal spring** with the left/right arrows in IB.  This is equivalent to setting `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`.
5. Do I want the **distance** between the **left** hand side of my view and the left hand side of its container to change when the width of the container changes?  If so, **disable** the **left strut** in IB.  This is equivalent to setting `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`.
6. Do I want the **distance** between the **right** hand side of my view and the right hand side of its container to change when the width of the container changes?  If so, **disable** the **right strut** in IB.  This is equivalent to setting `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`.

Comment: thanks for this - unfortunatley I've followed this but it still doesn't seem to fix the overlapping issue I have between subviews when going to landscape...there's nothing in XCode which really locks the bottom of one view to the top of the next view so they same positioned neatly stacked after orientation change it seems?  I'll also clarify in my post I actually have a menu bar at the top too....

Comment: had another go at adjusting the permutations and managed to get it  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this problem, try re-sizing the textView directly in scrollView delegate scrollViewDidRotate:

Comment: which class is scrollViewDidRotate a method of? i.e. how to I use in relation to the controller view *.m file I'm working with?