# Autoresize all UIScrollView subviews properly on orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, rotation, autoresize

I have:

- 1 paging scroll view at the bottom (like a panel) that is initially at 768x100 pixels, which is set up to stretch to 1024 when iPad rotates to landscape.
- 2 subviews, each 768x100 pixels big; one at origin 0,0, and one at origin 768,0. In portrait, the user can swipe left and right to switch between these panels.

When I rotate to landscape, the subviews stay the same size even though autoresizing is correct. They also stay at the same position, which means the right hand pane now appears 256 pixels "in" from the right.

Is there no way to fix this using autoresizing? Do I have to adjust the subviews on rotation manually?

Comment: If you are using IB then it can be done using autosizing.

Comment: I am using IB. Are you sure? Will play around with the attributes. I have autosizing set to flexible width & flexible height. I also have all the margins flexible. I could try setting left non-flex for left hand and vice versa for right, but they should resize still, I'd think.

Comment: Wait. They are resizing. You're right. Not updating contentSize seems to be the issue. Post as answer?

Comment: Yeah i have posted a short answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use autosizing on the interface builder.

Comment: I've gotten this to almost work, but the origin is still unchanged. Any idea what the resizing should look like? I've tried flipping the flexibles on left and right side around and such, without luck. Oh and unless I'm missing something, you have to also override setFrame: to change the contentSize to fit the new orientation. Do you not do this?

Comment: If you use autosizing on all elements for the orientations then its not necessary to set frame.

Comment: I didn't say "set frame" I said "change the contentSize ON setFrame"... And I do have autosizing. I'm doing this manually for now, but would really like to see an example of this working "natively".

Answer (score 0):

If the interface builder approach does not work or if you have complex subviews you need to realign, then you could do this -

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
       interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        /* handle resizing here*/
    }
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
    }
}
```

I could be wrong, also [**check this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886243/how-do-get-two-uitextviews-in-interface-builder-to-align-properly-when-going-to)

Comment: I know how to resize, thanks. The question isn't how to do it, the question is if I have to do it or not. Going down that path tends to be a bad idea as it requires more and more "manual" changes the more you put in.

Comment: Not necessarily, to give the user optimal experience in both orientations you need to take the pain to do this. It's not that manual if you think about it. It's one of the points Apple mentions in their `Human Interface Guidelines for Designing Apps on iOS`.

Comment: Really? I looked at the guidelines and read the "Handle Orientation Changes" part through and saw nothing encouraging users to do this... will read more and see what I find. Thanks.

Comment: Why realign in 'shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation'? eluding to resizing regardless of actually rotating (could return false). Should View Resizing not take place in 'willRotateToInterfaceOrientation' or didRotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to adjust the subviews manually. Because the UIScrollView's contentSize property define the size of the view displayed for Span&Zoom. It normally does not have any relation with the container (i.e. scrollview) size.